# Failed to get properties: Unit name mariadb-extra@.socket is missing the instance name

Tags: linux, mysql, debian, mariadb, socket

I've recently upgraded my MariaDB servers from 10.1 to 10.6 and now when I restart services for example wildfly, I get this message :

```
sudo service wildfly restart
Failed to get properties: Unit name mariadb-extra@.socket is missing the instance name.
Failed to get properties: Unit name mariadb@.socket is missing the instance name.
```

How can I get rid of this ?

Answer (score 2):

Problem is Debian `/usr/bin/service`-script which tries to activate sockets that belongs to service file and mariadb@.socket is for multi instance MariaDB and can't be activated without a name as error message suggests. To prevent error/warning please start to use systemd `systemctl` directly:

```
systemctl start wildfly
```

Please see closed upstream JIRA bug [MDEV-27715](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-27715)